# Getting the text event instead of the countdown

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

My countdown has been running well since 2 days but now I am getting a weird problem.

The script is constantly showing GRB is Finished instead of still running the countdown until the date that is supposed to be Sunday at 9PM to 10PM +8 GMT.

Can someone point me to the correct direction, I tried everything I could but I don't get why it shows me that.
I also tried to see if on console, there was some bug but there isn't.

You can see it on my website itself:
http://shaiyaunite.org

Here is the whole script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jq){
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get todays date and time
    var d = new Date(Date.now());
    // Passer en UTC
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset());
    // Repasser en n'importe timezone (même si là, c'est plus intelligent de changer le script pour rester en UTC) :
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 8 * 60); // Ici GMT + 8, attention toutefois au DST s'il y en a dans ta timezone
    var countDownDate = getNextDayOfWeek(d,0,21);

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - d;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toString();
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toString();
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)).toString();
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000).toString();

    // Add 0 when value are < 10
    hours = (hours < 10) ? "0"+hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0"+minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0"+seconds : seconds;

    var grb = jq("#grb");
    // Display the result in the element with id="grb"
    grb.html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s");

    // If the count down is finished, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        var one_hour = -60 * -60 * -1000;
        if(distance < one_hour){

            grb.html("GRB is finished!");
        }else{
            grb.html("GRB is open!");
        }
    }
}, 1000);

function getTextMonth(month){
switch(month){
    case 1:
        month = "January";
    break;
    case 2:
        month = "February";
    break;
    case 3:
        month = "March";
    break;
    case 4:
        month = "April";
    break;
    case 5:
        month = "May";
    break;
    case 6:
        month = "June";
    break;
    case 7:
        month = "July";
    break;
    case 8:
        month = "August";
    break;
    case 9:
        month = "September";
    break;
    case 10:
        month = "October";
    break;
    case 11:
        month = "November";
    break;
    case 12:
        month = "December";
    break;
}
return month;


function getNextDayOfWeek(date, dayOfWeek, hour) {
var resultDate = new Date(Date.now());
resultDate.setDate(date.getDate() + (7 + dayOfWeek - date.getDay()) % 7);
resultDate.setHours(hour,0,0,0);
return resultDate;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the start value in the next loop?

Comment: It shoud relaunch the countdown from the ending date so after the GRB is finished normally but doesn't seems to work :/